# Shell script that passes date from file to mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, scripting, debian

How can I execute a linux batch script that reads a date from a file, passes it as a parameter into mysql script and then write current date into file?

Something like:

1. read datefile   (one line with date as yyyy-mm-dd)
2. mysql -u user -ppass < update.sql
3. update.sql:   update table set x=y where date between $datefrom1 and curdate()
4. write curdate() to datefile

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof of concept to learn from. You can figure the solution from here.

```
$ cat data
fox
$ aa=`cat data`
$ echo $aa
fox
$ echo The quick $aa jumped
The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog
$ echo The quick $aa jumped over the lazy dog > bb
$ more bb
The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

Comment: So in my mysql script, I place $datefrom1 throughout the script.  Then I set $datefrom1 = 'cat datefile'   then I can perform mysql -u user -ppass > update.sql   then I echo $(date) > datefile     Will that work?

Comment: The '$' in the start of the line is the prompt. Do not type it. Also use mysql ... < update.sql (watch the direction).